# Find closest entries in MongoDB to coordinates

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am having a hard time finding items which are closest to a set of lat/lon.

My objects have their lat/lon stored as such:

```
 "address": "some_address",
    "city": "some_city",
    "coordinates": [
      32.214048,
      -84.361727
    ]
```

This is the query I am currently using, when I use it I get no results back, not even an empty array.

`collection.find({coordinates: {$near: [40.296898, -111.694647] }, $maxDistance:100})`

How can I query my objects to find the closest ones?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are three main things you must do.

1. You must save your coordinates in in the [longitude, latitude] order. This is required by mongo as you can see in [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/geospatial-indexes/#spherical). So, your data must look like

```
    {
        "address": "some_address",
        "city": "some_city",
        "coordinates": [
          -84.361727,
          32.214048
        ]
    }
```

2. Once you have your data properly set, you must create a **2dsphere** index in order to work with geoNear.

```
    db.collection.createIndex({coordinates: "2dsphere"})
```

3. Then you must fix your query. Here need to pass a $nearSphere with geometry properties, that is where you put your coordinates in the order we said before [longitude, latitude]

```
    db.collection.find({ 
        coordinates: { 
            $nearSphere: { 
                $geometry: { 
                    type: "Point", 
                    coordinates: [ -84.361727 , 32.214048 ] 
                }, 
                $maxDistance: 100 
            } 
        } 
    })
```

Comment: Is there a way to tell how far each entry is from the given point? Or is that only provided with geoNear()?

Comment: Well, I think it only can be obtained though geoNear, however, there are two ways on how to achieve that. Using the aggregation framework https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/ or or the geoNear command https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/geoNear/